# How does rotations work in the webgl graphics pipeline?

Tags: webgl

I have a implemented this tutorial https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-rotation.html but there's some things I don't understand.

In the shader the rotations is applied by creating a new `vec2 rotatedPosition`:

```
  ...
  vec2 rotatedPosition = vec2(
      a_position.x * u_rotation.y + a_position.y * u_rotation.x,
      a_position.y * u_rotation.y - a_position.x * u_rotation.x);
  ...
```

but how exactly is this actually providing a rotation? With `rotation=[1,0]->u_rotation=vec2(1,0)` the object is rotated 90 degrees. I understand the unit circle maths, what I don't understand is how the simple equation above actually performs the transformation.

`a_position` is a vec2, `u_rotation` is a vec2. If i do the calculation above *outside* the shader and feed it into the shader as a position, that position simply becomes `vec2 rotatedPosition = vec2(y, -x)`. But *inside* the shader then this calculation `vec2 rotatedPosition = vec2( a_position.x * u_rota...` performs a rotation (it does not become `vec2(y, -x)` but instead uses a rotation matrix).

What magic ensures that `rotatedPostion` actually gets rotated when the vec2 is calculated inside the shader, as opposed to outside the shader? What 'tells' the vertex shader that it's supposed to do a rotation matrix calculation, as opposed to normal arithmetic?

Answer (score 1):

Check the 2D rotation [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). The magic (linear algebra) is that your `u_rotation` vector probably has the `cos` and `sin` from the angle `θ` in radians.

The rotation is counterclockwise of a two-dimensional Cartesian coordinate system. Example:

```
// your point
a = (a.x, a.y) = (1, 0)

// your angle in radians
θ = PI/2

// intermediaries
cos(θ) = 0
sin(θ) = 1

// your rotation vector
r = (r.x, r.y) = (cos(θ), sin(θ)) = (0, 1)

// your new `v` vector, the rotation of `a` around
// the center of the coordinate system, with angle `θ`
// be careful, 'v' to be a new vector, because if you try
// to reuse 'a' or 'r' you will mess the math 
v.x = a.x * r.x - a.y * r.y = 1 * 0 - 0 * 1 = 0
v.y = a.x * r.y + a.y * r.x = 1 * 1 + 0 * 0 = 1
```

Here `v` will be `x=0, y=1` as it should be. Your code does not seem to do the same.

Maybe you also want to know, how to rotate the point around an arbitrary other point, not always around the center of the coordinate system. You have to translate your point relatively to the new rotation center, rotate it, then translate it back like this:

```
// your arbitrary point to rotate around
center = (10, 10)

// translate (be careful not to subtract `a` from `center`)
a = a - center;

// rotate as before
...

// translate back
a = a + center;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I'm asking is more related to the implementation details of webgl. I feel there's a shortcut applied somewhere in webgl which I dont understand and which I need an answer to for another project. One theory I had is that performing arithmetic within a vec2 causes rotations? Another theory I had is that maybe the `a_position` which gets fed into the shader as triangles is absolute around some point (sort like css property transform)

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. The rotation of a 2D vector is done as I have wrote, if you want to know about the graphics pipeline that is another question.

Comment: It's the graphics pipeline which I'm after. I think I can dig out an answer on my own now that i know what it's called, thank you again.

Comment: The pipeline is fundamentally different question, that has little to do with 2D rotation per se. I think you are better of to ask another question, or read here: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview . That is for OpenGL but the principle is the same. Keep in mind that WebGPU is comming.